# How can I index a hash field in MongoDB or Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following mongo document:

```
{
  _id: 'someid',
  name: 'John Doe',
  address: {
    city: 'Osaka',
    country: 'Japan'
  }
}
```

How do I index by city and country?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#indexes-on-embedded-fields):

> **Indexing on Embedded Fields**
>
> You can create indexes on fields embedded in sub-documents, just as you can index top-level fields in documents. [...] Instead, indexes on embedded fields allow you to use a “dot notation,” to introspect into sub-documents.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> db.people.ensureIndex( { "address.zipcode": 1 } )
> ```

Mongoid uses the same [Dot Notation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html):

> You can define indexes on embedded document fields as well.
>
> ```
> class Person
>   include Mongoid::Document
>   embeds_many :addresses
>   index "addresses.street"
> end
> ```

So you want something like this:

```
class C
  include Mongoid::Document
  index 'address.city'
  index 'address.country'
  #...
end
```

Comment: But address is not an embedded document. It is a simple hash field.

Comment: @CoffeeBite: Have you tried it? I set up a quick collection that matches your sample data, did an `ensureIndex` on `address.city`, and then `db.x.find({'address.city': 'c'}).explain()` indicates `"BtreeCursor address.city_1"` is used for the query and that indicates that the index is being used.